# Basic RSA theory: how does the server "remember" the private key

Tags: php, ajax, rsa, public-key-encryption

So far, my understanding of a password transfer using a public key algorithm is as follows:

1. AJAX call to PHP page retrieves generated public key
2. Password is encrypted using the public key
3. AJAX call to PHP page transmits the encrypted string
4. PHP page decrypts the string with the private key

First off, my understanding may be wrong; please correct me if it is. Assuming it isn't, there is a slight problem nonetheless: the private key must be generated in step 1, but it is only used in step 4. My question is: how can I get the PHP page to "remember" the private key that it generated in the first call, to be used in the second?

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: the question is not very clear.. usually, priv/pub keys are not generated "on the fly" for each request, they are read from stored  files on the server, so, your step 1 would read and offer the pub key from the disk, step 4 read the private counterpart. or is there some specific requirement to generate a new pair every time in your case?

Comment: Are you working on a JavaScript login system that encrypts login passwords client-side on a non-SSL connection? Might be an idea to edit your question, and make the first paragraph a brief description of what you are actually wanting to achieve.

Comment: @Bluefire That doesn't explain very much... I guess you should simply use HTTPS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can I get the PHP page to "remember" the private key that it generated in the first call, to be used in the second?

Using [**sessions**](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php).